# Mongoose aggregate lookup returns empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been looking the issue I have I found so many problems related to my issue but It did not work for me. I don't know what I am missing!

In my schema I did it like this:

```
 student: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Student',
      required: true,
    },
```

In the logic I did like this:

```
 const agg = await MarksModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          student: studentObj._id,
          course: courseObj._id,
        },
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            subject: '$subject',
            course: '$course',
            student: '$student',
            semester: '$semester',
          },
          totalTheoryMarks: { $sum: '$theoryMarks' },
          totalPracticalMarks: { $sum: '$practicalMarks' },
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'Student', // I tried students, student, Students & Student.
          localField: 'student',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'student',
        },
      },
    ])
```

Everything is fine but I always return some output like this:

```
 [
   {
     _id: {
       subject: 60c700aaf6deb877000028c4,
       course: 60b8fe0fccbe980f70e6542d,
       student: 60c1f2a7f12ac51544035a12,
       semester: 3
     },
     totalTheoryMarks: 30,
     totalPracticalMarks: 30,
     student: [] // This is the issue I have
   }
 ]
```

Comment: localField: 'student' => localField: '_id.student’?

Comment: what does it mean this line?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I solved my issue by swiping $lookup and $group. $group uses a reference array from $lookup which is from top to bottom.